# dataframe with dynamic when condition using with column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Scala code for computing a new column with using withcolumn function in my hardcoded code which looks something like this

```
 combinedinputdf
  .withColumn("AMGClassRule", when(col("CoreSectorLevel1Code") === "Derivatives" && col("CoreSectorLevel2Code") === "Caps" && col("FAS157Flavor") === "SPRD", "1")
      //.when(col("CoreSectorLevel1Code") === "Derivatives" && col("CoreSectorLevel2Code") === "Caps" && col("FAS157Flavor") === "SPRD", "2")
      .when(col("CoreSectorLevel1Code") === "Derivatives" && col("FAS157Flavor") === "TRSY" && col("DerivativeType") === "TROR", "3")
      .when(col("InDefaultInd") === "Y" , "4")
```

This works as expected.

But I want to dynamically add or modify the when condition while executing  based on table or CSV

second table looks like this [image: Tables with rules]

so at runtime I can read this table into either dataframe or Map and iterate through rules of the table and assign a value to my output

How do I go about doing this dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be achieved dynamically by approaching the creation of `when` conditions in a somewhat abstract manner.

To make it more readable, let's create a dedicated wrapper object:

```
case class WhenCondition(valuesToCheck: Seq[(String, Any)], valueIfMatches: Any)
```

`valuesToCheck` field contains a sequence of tuples for all applicable conditions for the expression to generate. The first element of each tuple is the name of the column, the second is the value to match with. For example: `("CoreSectorLevel1Code", "Derivatives")`.

`valueIfMatches` corresponds to the second arg to pass to `when`: "1", "3" or "4" from the example.

We will need a function that reads conditions from the source table and returns a sequence of `WhenCondition` instances:

```
private def readConditions(args: Any*): Seq[WhenCondition] = {
  ??? // impl depends on how you read the source data
}

// for the example of the question, this function should return:
val conditions = Seq(
  WhenCondition(Seq(("CoreSectorLevel1Code", "Derivatives"), ("CoreSectorLevel2Code", "Caps"), ("FAS157Flavor", "SPRD")), "1"),
  WhenCondition(Seq(("CoreSectorLevel1Code", "Derivatives"), ("FAS157Flavor", "TRSY"), ("DerivativeType", "TROR")), "3"),
  WhenCondition(Seq(("InDefaultInd", "Y")), "4")
)
```

*Update*

We'll also need a function that produces a chaining of `when` calls:

```
private def chainWhen(chained: Column, remaining: Seq[(Column, Any)]): Column =
  remaining match {
    case Nil => chained
    case head :: tail => chainWhen(chained.when(head._1, head._2), tail)
  }
```

Now we create a `dynamicWhen` function that transfroms the sequence of `WhenCondition`:

```
private def dynamicWhen(parsedConditions: Seq[WhenCondition]): Option[Column] = {
  // first, we transform a WhenCondition object into a tuple of args (Column, Any) for the target "when" function
  val conditions = parsedConditions.map(whenCondition => {
    val condition = whenCondition.valuesToCheck
                                 .map(cond => col(cond._1) === cond._2)
                                 .reduce(_ && _)
    (condition, whenCondition.valueIfMatches)
  })
  // if there weren't any input conditions, we return None, otherwise we chain the transformation and wrap it into Some
  conditions match {
    case Nil => None
    case head :: tail => Some(chainWhen(when(head._1, head._2), tail))
  }
}
```

And the original hard-coded call can be replaced with

```
// produce the optional chained dynamic "whens".
val whenConditions = dynamicWhen(conditions)

// map it in a DataFrame with a new column or keep the original one, if there were no "whens".
val result = whenConditions.map(cond => df.withColumn("AMGClassRule", cond))
                           .getOrElse(df)
```

Finally, a short test with faky data:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("Derivatives", "Caps", "SPRD", "x", "N"),
  ("Derivatives", "Caps", "SPRD", "TROR", "Y"),
  ("Derivatives", "Caps", "TRSY", "x", "Y"),
  ("Derivatives", "Caps", "TRSY", "TROR", "N"),
  ("Derivatives", "Caps", "zzzz", "x", "N")
).toDF("CoreSectorLevel1Code", "CoreSectorLevel2Code", "FAS157Flavor", "DerivativeType", "InDefaultInd")

val result = ... // transformations above
result.show(false)

+--------------------+--------------------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
|CoreSectorLevel1Code|CoreSectorLevel2Code|FAS157Flavor|DerivativeType|InDefaultInd|AMGClassRule|
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
|Derivatives         |Caps                |SPRD        |x             |N           |1           |
|Derivatives         |Caps                |SPRD        |TROR          |Y           |1           |
|Derivatives         |Caps                |TRSY        |x             |Y           |4           |
|Derivatives         |Caps                |TRSY        |TROR          |N           |3           |
|Derivatives         |Caps                |zzzz        |x             |N           |null        |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

*End-of-update*

*Update 2*

Example of reading of conditions from a DataFrame.

Supposing we have the following condition descriptions stored in a DataFrame:

```
val rulesDf = Seq(
  ("Derivatives", "%", "%", "16"),
  ("Derivatives", "Fx Options", "%", "17"),
  ("Derivatives", "Futures", "%", "48")
).toDF("CoreSectorLevel1Code", "CoreSectorLevel2Code", "FAS157Flavor", "rule")

rulesDf.show(false)

+--------------------+--------------------+------------+----+
|CoreSectorLevel1Code|CoreSectorLevel2Code|FAS157Flavor|rule|
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+----+
|Derivatives         |%                   |%           |16  |
|Derivatives         |Fx Options          |%           |17  |
|Derivatives         |Futures             |%           |48  |
+--------------------+--------------------+------------+----+
```

We can read and transform them into `WhenCondition` wrappers using the following:

```
private def readConditions(): Seq[WhenCondition] = {
  val ruleColumnName = "rule"
  val ruleColumnIndex = rulesDf.schema.fieldIndex(ruleColumnName)
  val conditionColumns = rulesDf.schema.fieldNames.filter(_ != ruleColumnName).toSeq
  rulesDf.rdd.map(row => {
    val valuesToCheck = conditionColumns.map(colName => (colName, row.get(row.fieldIndex(colName))))
    val rule = row(ruleColumnIndex)
    WhenCondition(valuesToCheck, rule)
  }).collect().toSeq
}

readConditions().foreach(println)

// outputs:
WhenCondition(mutable.ArrayBuffer((CoreSectorLevel1Code,Derivatives), (CoreSectorLevel2Code,%), (FAS157Flavor,%)),16)
WhenCondition(mutable.ArrayBuffer((CoreSectorLevel1Code,Derivatives), (CoreSectorLevel2Code,Fx Options), (FAS157Flavor,%)),17)
WhenCondition(mutable.ArrayBuffer((CoreSectorLevel1Code,Derivatives), (CoreSectorLevel2Code,Futures), (FAS157Flavor,%)),48)
```

*End-of-update 2*

Comment: I ma getting an error  stating when() can only be applied on a Column previously generated by when() function
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.when(Column.scala:499)

Comment: Yes, I think that it is caused by `lit(true)`. I'll need to correct the example with an appropriate start for `foldLeft`.

Comment: thanks.. if I can run this example I will accept the answer.. btw this would also work  if I need to sort the sequence  to order the rules. correct ?

Comment: Fixed and improved the answer with a working example. _"btw this would also work if I need to sort the sequence to order the rules. correct ?"_: the ordering of the rules is up to you, it should not matter for this transformation.

Comment: Lastly,  can you just point me on how to implement private def readConditions(args: Any*): Seq[WhenCondition] = {
  ??? // impl depends on how you read the source data
} if I have a dataframe where i can have N numbers of condition column  and 1 column for the result

Comment: If the conditions are already loaded in a DataFrame, then you can just select the rows you need from it and transfrom each one into a `WhenCondition` wrapper. Or even, having a DataFrame with conditions, the `readConditions` function would not be necessary: that could be done inside `dynamicWhen`, might be something like ex: `val conditions = dfWithConditions.collect().map(extractConditionsFromRow(_))... etc`

Comment: the rules data frame I have is like the picture I have in my question.. how do I get the column name  and condition  WhenCondition(Seq(("CoreSectorLevel1Code", "Derivatives"), ("CoreSectorLevel2Code", "Caps"), ("FAS157Flavor", "SPRD")), "1"), ?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Hi antot.. I implemented the above example but now I am getting this error. Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: ArrayBuffer(((InDefaultInd <=> Y),4)) (of class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer). When I hard code the same  condition it works . I have tried with using as insatanceof but to no avail.